# Symfony 2 change translations path

Tags: symfony, directory, bundle

I cannot seem to figure out how to change the path from reading from the translations directory in a bundle to a specific directory instead.

Comment: Please be more specific. In which dir you want your translations?

Comment: It would be /cloudfiles/translation_files_dev/

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php#L695 you must add paths to `translator.paths` config.

```
framework:
  translator: 
    paths: ["/cloudfiles/translation_files_dev"]
```